# Android memory types, allocations and reportings

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, dalvik

I'm trying to understand the memory used by Android applications, since it seems like my app is leaking memory at a point where I've no control over memory usage.

- The settings application lists application memory usage (e.g. 90 MB for my app). How is this number calculated?
- `adb shell ps | grep 'myapp'` shows a resident set size that's, for my app, is roughly 20MB more than what's shown under settings app

My guess is that the first one is Android's PSS and the second one is the regular Linux RSS, but not sure...

My app, is a phonegap app, i.e. a big webview and runs couple of network related stuff on the native Android side (sending and receiving UDP packets). While not touching the device the Heap reported in Eclipse DDMS does not change (12MB of 15MB used on my SGS3), but the memory under `settings` app as well as the memory reported in the `ps` output grows slightly over time. Roughly 1MB per 30mins, but sometimes jumps up 10MB or more and never comes down again. So this really looks like a memory leak. I did not code JNI stuff, i.e. the whole networking part is using the Android SDK.

- What could be a possible cause of this experienced memory growth?
- How to debug non-java-heap memory issues on Android?

Comment: Leaking view references :) Wait, memory under settings? You mean space used? With data caches, private appdata and all that?

Comment: Some help with native memory leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386339/how-to-use-ddms-for-memory-leaks-in-c-code/15398651#15398651